# Compile error: Cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

I am getting an error when trying to compile that I cannot figure out. I have managed to fix the other errors I had (I think, they no longer list at least). I have tried to figure it out and clearly I am not understanding the issue. 
Error that occurs:

```
PastPresentFuture.java:34: error: method determine_past_present_future in 
class PastPresentFuture cannot be applied to given types;
 determine_past_present_future(pastpresentfuture);
 ^
  required: int,int,int
found: String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

here is where it is called

```
pastpresentfuture = determine_past_present_future(User_month, User_day, User_year);
```

and this is the relevant code

```
public static String determine_past_present_future(int a, int b, int c) {
        int Current_year = 2017;
        int Current_month = 9;
        int Current_day = 10;
        String date;

        if ((c < Current_year) || (c > Current_year)) {
            date = "not this year";
        } else if ((a < Current_month)) {
            date = "in an earlier month this year";
        } else if ((a > Current_month)) {
            date = "in a later month this year";
        } else if ((a == Current_month)) {
            date = "this month";
        }
        return date;
    }
```

edit* figured it out I messed up a method call while watching hurricane updates and was too focused on the wrong area to fix that didn't need to be fixed.

Comment: You need to post the code where you are calling the method

Comment: What's `pastpresentfuture`? Did you forget the comma separator?

Comment: Unrelated, but have you not learned about `else if {`?

Comment: What arguments do you pass to this function?

Comment: Show the method from which you call the `determine_past_present_future()` method, i.e., the function call statement.

Comment: pastpresentfuture = determine_past_present_future(User_month, User_day, User_year);

Comment: @Drew That code wouldn't cause this error. Either you didn't save your file before compiling, or error is caused by different line.

Comment: Error message states that problem is `determine_past_present_future(pastpresentfuture);` not `determine_past_present_future(User_month, User_day, User_year);`

Comment: Thanks Phsemo I misnamed a different call on my output trying to watch the latest on the hurricane while doing it... lesson learnt from this = concentrate on one thing at a time

Answer (score 1):

As error clearly says

```
  required: int,int,int
  found: String
```

This means, you are calling `determine_past_present_future` method by passing `String` instead you need to pass 3 parameters of type `int`.